# Angular Service - return private value versus assignment by reference to private value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, service, reference

Discussing with a coworker the difference between getting a return value of a private array versus an assignment to a variable that is a reference to the private array , but couldn't think of a good reason why the following would yield different results:

**Controller**

```
app.controller("MyController", ["MyService", function(MyService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.arrayAssign = [];

    ctrl.doSomething = function() {
        // Empty out array, usually assigned at one point, code is omitted for example
        ctrl.arrayAssign = []

        // This does not work, ctrl.arrayAssign = []
        ctrl.arrayAssign = MyService.serviceArray;

        // This works, ctrl.arrayAssign correctly assigned to serviceArray in MyService
        ctrl.arrayAssign = MyService.getServiceArray();
    }
}]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service("MyService", [function(){
    var service = this;
    var serviceArray = [];

    service.serviceArray = serviceArray;

    // This is called, either from controller above, or another controller
    service.assignToServiceArray = function(arr) {
        serviceArray = angular.copy(arr);
    };

    service.getServiceArray = function() {
        return serviceArray;
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

Note: ctrl.doSomething() is called after service.assignToServiceArray()

**What is a good explanation to why the two controller assignments above have different results as described?**

I thought service.serviceArray would expose the private array serviceArray and just become a reference to the private array (service.serviceArray = serviceArray), so a new assignment to serviceArray (i.e. from service.assignToServiceArray), should allow service.serviceArray to reference the new array assignment which can be accessed directly by a controller.

service.getServiceArray() would also expose the private variable serviceArray, but directly, as in I'm not trying to access a variable that is just a reference to the array (i.e. service.serviceArray above).

Would trying to assign a reference to a private variable not be ideal in this case and just returning a private value be favored? I'm probably missing something really obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service.serviceArray = serviceArray` assigns a reference to `[]` array to `serviceArray` property, not a reference to `serviceArray` variable.

When a new value is assigned to `serviceArray`, it is assigned to this variable and nothing else.

A good thing about [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) is that it accepts two arguments and allows to keep the reference to the object:

> If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.

So it would work with:

```
angular.copy(arr, serviceArray);
```

The service in fact misuses OOP features that are provided by JS. `service` service accepts a constructor function. There's no problems like this if it behaves like normal object constructor:

```
app.service("MyService", [function(){
    this.serviceArray = [];

    service.assignToServiceArray = function(arr) {
        this.serviceArray = arr;
    };

    service.getServiceArray = function() {
        return this.serviceArray;
    };

    // not needed
    // return service;
}]);
```

If `MyService.serviceArray` is supposed to be used after its reassignment, it should be referred everywhere only by its getter and setter methods. The actual reason for getters and setters in OOP is that the value is being kept private and never accessed from the outside directly. E.g. in view:

```
{{ vm.MyService.getServiceArray()[0] }}
```

Comment: quick question, in service.assignToServiceArray, does this.serviceArray become a reference to arr? in general javascript, using a constructor like this would make a reference to the passed in array.  in your experience, would you want a reference (if possible) or a copy of that array in your service? just seemed to me you'd want a copy in your service because passing references from different controllers could get messy, er unless you're careful and know what you're doing :P

Comment: Yes, it becomes a reference. It always depends if it should be copied or assigned. But I cannot inagine a scenario where several controllers should assign an array like that. Any way, there's nothing really bad with it, it is tidy and clean if it is covered with tests. If this array is used for ng-repeat, this won't cause a problem (maybe less performant than angular.copy but not sure about this).

Comment: makes sense, thanks for your input!  i was just thinking of the classic angular question "how do i share data between controllers" but i figure you would want each controller to reference (or even copy) the service's array and configure the setter to not reference the controller array

Comment: There's more than one right answer to the question, in the end it always depends on the case. I often end up with solutions that wouldn't be my first choice in vitro. Feel free to post a more specific question if you will have problems with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

When you call assignToServiceArray you assign serviceArray the local variable to point to a new array you don't update the reference or update the original array so service.serviceArray is still pointing at the empty array you started it off with... if you instead did angular.copy(arr,serviceArray) without the assignment you'd get the result where the actual array remains the same (same array object) but it's contents get emptied and repopulated in which case both service.serviceArray and serviceArray would have the updated array.  If I missed the question let me know.

Comment: gotcha! Figured that service.serviceArray was still referencing the old array from the initialization, wasn't too sure about how  the copy assigns a completely different array to serviceArray

Comment: Cool yeah slightly better formatted and clearer explanation from estus as well.